# Memory allocation failed when required more than 16GB contiguous memory

Tags: c++, linux, malloc, ubuntu-16.04, dynamic-memory-allocation

My workstation has 128GB memory. I cannot allocate an array that takes (contiguous) memory more than ~16GB. But I can allocate multiple arrays with each takes around 15GB.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int MM = 1000000;
int NN = 2200; // 2000 is okay, used ~16GB memory; 2200 produces Segmentation fault

double* testMem1d;
testMem1d  = (double*) malloc(MM*NN*sizeof(double));

double* testMem1d1; // NN=2000, allocate another array (or two) at the same time is okay
testMem1d1 = (double*) malloc(MM*NN*sizeof(double));

cout << "testMem1d allocated" << endl;
cin.get(); // here is okay, only malloc but not accessing the array element

cout << "testMem1d[MM*NN-1]=" << testMem1d[MM*NN-1]<< endl;
cout << "testMem1d1[MM*NN-1]=" << testMem1d1[MM*NN-1]<< endl;

// keep running and check the physical memory footprint
for (int tt=0;tt<1000;tt++)
{
    for (int ii=0; ii<MM*NN; ii++)
    {
        testMem1d[ii]=ii;
        testMem1d1[ii]=ii;
    }
    cout << "MM=" << MM << ", NN=" << NN << ", testMem1d[MM*NN-1]=" << testMem1d[MM*NN-1]<< endl;
}
}
```

Please ignore I am using malloc() in c++ if it is not an essential problem. (Is it?) I need/want to use malloc() for other reasons.

Some observations:
(1) Allocating multiple arrays, with each one smaller than 15GB, is fine
(2) Only do malloc() is fine. "Segmentation fault" when accessing the array elements.

I thought there might be some system settings that limited memory allocation. From "ulimit -a" everything seems fine. As the program can access 64-bit virtual address space, I couldn't find any reason that only limits the contiguous memory allocation.

OS: Ubunt 16.04. I tried g++ and icc with mcmodel=large. It seems irrelevant.

```
uname -a
Linux 4.4.0-143-generic #169-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 07:56:38 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ulimit -a 
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 515031
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 515031
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Edits:

(1) mallc() actually returns NULL [to mcleod_ideafix]

(2) [to zwol]

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         128809       18950      107840        1129        2018      107910
Swap:           974         939          35
```

Comment: "Only do malloc() is fine. "Segmentation fault" when accessing the array elements." . No, It's not fine. After calling malloc() you should test your returned pointer for NULL. If it is NULL, malloc() failed.

Comment: How much actual RAM + swap do you have? (if you don't know, the command 'free' will tell you)

Comment: Hi, @mcleod_ideafix, thanks, malloc() indeed returns NULL

Comment: Hi, @zwol, thanks, please see the updated info in Edits.

Comment: `MM*NN` is overflowing....

Comment: @KamilCuk Does it still overflow if you cast it to `size_t`? (Haven't checked.)

Comment: No, I mean cast the operands to `size_t`, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Okay, have now actually checked myself, and no it doesn't overflow if you do that.

Comment: The posted code is `C++` not `C`.  They are two different languages.  Please correct the `tags` on the question

Answer (score 7):

The multiplication `MM*NN*sizeof(double)` is left associative, so it happens as `(MM * NN) * sizeof(double)`. On a platform with 32-bit `int` having the equation `MM * NN` is equal to `2200000000` which cannot be represented in an 32-bit `int` and overflows (and undefined behavior happens) and wraps around which results in `-2094967296`. Then this value is promoted to common type with `sizeof(double)`, to `size_t`. This is a signed type to unsigned type conversion, where the signed value cannot be represented in an unsigned type, so the conversion is implementation-defined. In twos-complement with 64-bit `size_t` sign extension happens and it should result in `18446744071614584320`. Then this value is multiplied by `sizeof(double)` which I assume is equal to `8`, it overflows multiple times (which is safe, `size_t` unsigned) and results in `18446744056949813248` bytes. Your machine doesn't have that much memory, so `malloc` returns NULL.

That's why it's good to put `sizeof` as first operand in `malloc` call:

```
malloc(sizeof(double) * MM * NN);
```

in which case operands will be promoted to `size_t` before multiplication.

Still that wouldn't be enough, because in `testMem1d[MM*NN-1]` and in `ii<MM*NN` overflow still happens. So you should change the type of `MM` and `NN` to a type with enough bits to hold the result.

```
size_t MM = 1000000;
size_t NN = 2200;
```

Or cast the values to proper type before each multiplication that can overflow.

Note that statements `cout << "testMem1d[MM*NN-1]=" << testMem1d[MM*NN-1]<< endl; cout << "testMem1d1[MM*NN-1]=" << testMem1d1[MM*NN-1]<< endl;` are reading uninitialized memory.

Prefer using `new` in C++.

Comment: Just tried it on a server with plenty of memory, and although I didn't run it to completion, malloc happily returned non-NULL pointers (with your fix - and can reproduce the problem without the fix).

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right. Thanks. That was a bad test...